# How Do I append data from Sheet 1 which has filtered data to existing data in "Output" Sheet?

Tags: excel, vba

I have soem existing data that I have filtered in Sheet1. Now I want to paste this data in "Output" sheet, however after the last filled row. I am not sure, how through VBA can I let it know that this is the last row cause everytime I run the previous macro, the last row in Sheet 2 could be different.

Please help with the code, thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/find-last-used-cell-in-excel-vba

Comment: @FunThomas, that question is about formulas, not VBA (although you could use them).

Comment: @saura You can use `ActiveSheet.Range("a1").End(xlDown).Row` to get the row number of the last row (even if there are unfilled rows).

Comment: @Paul: What do you mean with "Formulas"? The linked question and answers deal with VBA, the question here deals with VBA and your comment also uses VBA. Note that you show code for `ActiveSheet` which would force the code to activate the Output sheet first (which is bad and not necessary). Also, using `End(xlDown)` fails on empty sheets and therefore is not a good solution

Comment: @FunThomas my mistake, I focused on a couple of solutions on that other page (like `=MAX(FILTER(ROW(A:A),NOT(ISBLANK(A:A))))` and forgot about the rest. You're right, the rest of the page is about VBA solutions.

Comment: @FunThomas agreed that ActiveSheet is probably not necessary, should be the actual sheet. Also, `End(xlDown)` fails on empty sheets but from the description I assumed that there is already data there (or at least a row of headings).